# Unity - character is not moving

Tags: unity, character

**What I'm trying to do**

I have a character - prefab. For this prefab I have one animation (idle), which works fine - I hit "Play" button and my character is in idle state. What I want is to try to move this character without implementing an animation (for now, only for test). So I wrote two scripts - one is the "engine" for movement and one is the controller for the character itself.

**What is wrong**

The thing is, that my character is not moving at all. I tried to debug the keyboards in the console and that works fine, so I assume that the inputs are good. I checked that twice in the Project Settings. I tried with two Unity versions and also I tried to start whole new project only with cubes, because I thought that maybe is something wrong with my character. That doesn't work either.

**MovementMotor.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementMotor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float gravityMultiplier = 1f;
    public float lerpTime = 10f;

    [HideInInspector]
    public CharacterController characterController;

    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 targetDirection = Vector3.zero;
    private float fallVelocity = 0f;

    public float distanceToGround = 0.1f;

    private bool isGrounded;
    private Collider myCollider;

    void Awake()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        myCollider = GetComponent<Collider>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        distanceToGround = myCollider.bounds.extents.y;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = OnGroundCheck();
        moveDirection = Vector3.Lerp(moveDirection, targetDirection, Time.deltaTime * lerpTime);
        moveDirection.y = fallVelocity;

        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        if (!isGrounded)
        {
            fallVelocity -= 90f * gravityMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    public bool OnGroundCheck()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (Physics.Raycast(myCollider.bounds.center, -Vector3.up, out hit, distanceToGround + 0.1f))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Move(Vector3 direction)
    {
        targetDirection = direction;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
        targetDirection = Vector3.zero;
    }

    public void Jump(float jumpPower)
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            fallVelocity = jumpPower;
        }
    }
}
```

**CharacterMovement.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private MovementMotor motor;

    public float moveMagnitude = 0.05f;
    public float speed = 0.7f;
    public float speedMoveWhileAttack = 0.1f;
    public float speedAttack = 1.5f;
    public float turnSpeed = 10f;
    public float jumpPower = 20f;

    private float speedMoveMultiplier = 1f;

    private Vector3 direction;
    private Animator animator;
    private Camera mainCamera;

    private string PARAMETER_STATE = "State";

    void Awake()
    {
        motor = GetComponent<MovementMotor>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        animator.applyRootMotion = false;
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    private Vector3 MoveDirection
    {
        get
        {
            return direction;
        }

        set
        {
            direction = value * speedMoveMultiplier;

            if (direction.magnitude > 0.1f)
            {
                var newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
            }
            direction *= speed * (Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, direction) + 1f) * 5f;
            motor.Move(direction);

            // AnimationMove(motor.characterController.velocity.magnitude * 0.1f);
        }
    }

    void Moving(Vector3 direction, float multiplier)
    {
        speedMoveMultiplier = 1 * multiplier;
        MoveDirection = direction;
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        motor.Jump(jumpPower);
    }

    void MovementAndJumping()
    {
        Vector3 moveInput = Vector3.zero;
        Vector3 forward = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-90, Vector3.up) * mainCamera.transform.right;

        moveInput += forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        moveInput += mainCamera.transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        moveInput.Normalize();
        Moving(moveInput.normalized, 1f);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**

Does the problem lies within the code or maybe I should look somewhere else?

Unity version: 2019.2.9f1

System: MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, in **MovementMotor.cs** `moveDirection` is always zero unless `distanceToGround` is greater than `0.1f`. This is because in **CharacterMovement.cs** `MovementAndJumping()` is never called. Calling this Method in `Update()` should fix the problem.

**CharacterMovement.cs**

```
void Update()
{
    MovementAndJumping();
}
```

Comment: You're brilliant:) I didn't think about it, I searched everywhere but now it works like a charm. Thank you very much:)